# How to reset stencil rotation in texture paint mode?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Sometimes I am accidentially rotating the stencil. Is there a way to reset the rotation of the stencil to 0? Pressing CTRL+Z for undoing does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **Angle** to **0**.

You can also use this value to precisely rotate your stencil.

[image: 1]